# Disable auto form validation in ant react

Tags: reactjs, antd

https://ant.design/components/form/

Giving this new lib a try, so far so good. very easy to use, but I'm now stuck in stopping the forms from automatically validating and displaying green ticks all over the place.

```
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} novalidate>
          <FormItem {...this.formItemLayout} label="Auto Synchronise Data" hasFeedback>
            {getFieldDecorator('name')(<Switch checked={this.props.settings.sync} onChange={this.changeCondition} />)}
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem {...this.formItemLayout} label="Clear local database" hasFeedback>
            {getFieldDecorator('name', {})(<Button type="danger" onClick={this.showModal}>Clear database</Button>)}
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
</div>
```

I'm actually only using the form component as I want a form style layout for a settings page. Every time a select the "switch" component in the form it then decides to show a green tick next to every form item in the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that because of the `hasFeedback` attribute?

Comment: ah ha! thanks, I did not see that.